# How exactly do we do Gauss elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

> This is a matrix:
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1\\
> 1 & 2 & 3\\
> 1 & 3 & k
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
> x\\
> y\\
> z
> \end{bmatrix}=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3\\
> 6\\
> 4+k
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find $k$ so that it has no unique solution. Solve the equations for this value of $k$.

I found $k = 5$ by using $\text{determinant}=0$.

Then I tried Gauss elimination, from what I understand from my lecturer, I use the 3 rules of Gauss elimination to solve, I just randomly use whatever I need to achieve echelon form. I have come to this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

The answer is

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Where does the $t$ come from? Does it involve eigenvalues?

Comment: For your future reference, the word `I` is capitalized in English.

Comment: no answers yet... bad timezone i live in...

Comment: The $t$ is coming from the fact that for $k=5$ the system has infinitely many solutions (which fits in with "find $k$ so that it has no unique solution"). The answer is the parametric form of the solution set, where $t$ is a free parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not row reduce correctly. Since we are told that there are infinitely many solutions, we know that the final result should have free variables, so there should be at most two pivots. We should get:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\
1 & 3 & 5 & 9 \\
\end{array}\right]
\sim
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 6 \\
\end{array}\right]
\sim
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
Translating back to a system, we have:
\begin{cases}
x - z = 0 \\
y + 2z = 3
\end{cases}
Taking $z = t$ and solving for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$, we conclude that the general solution is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}t \\ 3 - 2t \\ t\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
+
t\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What is the final form of row reduce,all diagonal 1? when does it end?
Can you further explain on row reduce? are there specific steps to follow? thanks

how do i know i am supposed to take z = t?

Comment: See how the bottom row is all zeros? This means we know nothing about $z$ at all. So we'll just set it to a "free parameter", $t$, and allow that to vary. In general, you'll get one parameter per zeroed-out-row (after row-reduction, of course).

Comment: @HenrySwanson thanks for explaining z=t, can you explain the row reduction?

Comment: After Gauss elimination, you get a matrix in [reduced row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form). The way I think of it is: The upper left corner is an identity matrix, the upper right is whatever, and the bottom rows are zeroes: $\left[ \begin{smallmatrix} I & F \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right]$. From there, you can permute the columns if you want.

Comment: @HenrySwanson Thanks, i will figure out

Answer (score 4):

By Gauss-Jordan elimination I get the following:

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\
  1 & 3 & k & 4+k
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 2 &k-1& 1+k
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 &k-5& k-5
\end{array}\right)$$

In the next step I would like to divide the last row by $k-5$. Notice that this is valid only for $k-5\ne0$, i.e., $k\ne 5$.

---

If $\boxed{k\ne5}$ I get
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 &k-5& k-5
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

I see that for $k\ne5$ I have the unique solution $(1,1,1)$.

I can check that this is indeed a solution by pluggin these values into the original system:
\begin{align*}
1+1+1&=3\\
1+2+3&=6\\
1+3+k&=4+k
\end{align*}

---

For $\boxed{k=5}$ I get
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 0 &-1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

This equation has infinitely many solutions $(t,3-2t,t)$, $t\in\mathbb R$, as explained in Adriano's answer.